# Error validating ipv6 address .Net

Tags: .net, ipv6

```
private bool ValidateIpAddress(string ipAddress)
    {
        if (IPAddress.TryParse(ipAddress, out IPAddress address) && address.ToString()==ipAddress)
        {
            switch (address.AddressFamily)
            {
                case System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork:
                    return true;
                case System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6:
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I am using this method to validate my string as ipv4 or ipv6 address but it show not valid at test -2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334

Answer (score 1):

This is because you *also* check that the IP address' representation as a string is the same as your input:

```
if (... && address.ToString()==ipAddress)
```

The address in question can be parsed correctly, but it can be written in a shortened form, but the following two string are not equal:

- `2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334`
- `2001:db8:85a3::8a2e:370:7334`

I'd also argue that capitalization is irrelevant for the hexadecimal representation, so you should at least do a case-insensitive comparison. But in general I'd probably ditch the requirement that the strings have to match (Why do they have to, if you already determined that the string *is* a valid IP address?). If you absolutely have to retain that requirement, you probably have to convert the address manually to the format you require.

**EDIT:** Apparently your IPv4 address has to have a specific format, so you could additionally just validate the general structure via a regular expression:

```
var regex = @"(?ix)
              ^\d+(\.\d+){3}$ # IPv4 address with all four octets
              |
              ^[0-9a-f]{4}(:[0-9a-f]{4}){7}$ # IPv6 address without any shortening";
if (... && Regex.IsMatch(ipAddress, regex))
```

Now, this is a whole other can of worms, though, but since the validation of addresses by `IPAddress` is not strict enough for you, this would add the flexibility to force specific formats.

Comment: But if I do not use this then it is showing the wrong result when I try to validate Ipv4 Addresses Test value- "153". It is converting it into 0.0.0.153 and mark it as write ipv4 address.

Comment: @AshuGarg: But `153` *is* a valid IPv4 address, which can usually be written as just an integer as well. For example, Google's public DNS server has the address `8.8.8.8` or `134744072`. Both should work in most applications. If you want to prevent *integers* from being considered a valid IP address, then perhaps you should check for the string *also* representing an integer and reject in that case. Alternatively you could add that check to only the IPv4 `switch` case: `case AddressFamily.InterNetworkV4: return !int.TryParse(ipAddress, out int dummy);`

Comment: @AshuGarg: I'd suggest you try figuring out what exact formats you want to accept and reject and determine a suitable algorithm to do so. Surely there must be a reason why your requirements are different from what IPAddress can parse. And this also means that you cannot really use that way of validating the address. You could add a regex validation to check whether the general format is your expected one, and use IPAddress only to validate that the address is in fact valid.